# How to login from remote server to my own PC?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

For the experiment purpose I need to login to my own PC from the remote PCs which are under the same domain, i.e: university network. How can I do remote login in this case using SSH?

As an example, I have accounts in two machines in University X which are `me@machine_a.cs.x.ca` and `me@machine_b.cs.x.ca`, my personal laptop account is `nawshad@ubuntu`. What extra info do I need to provide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As daveh's answer points out, that could be as simple as just issuing `ssh nawshad@ipaddress`.

However, chances are that your PC is not accessible directly from the internet, i.e. it sits behind a router of some sort.

One option is to tell the router to let traffic to your PC pass through. How you do this depends on the router. This options only works if you have administrative access to the router, and that there are no other routers involved.

Another option is to create a reverse SSH tunnel, i.e. from your PC, you log into one (or both) of your university machines, creating at the same time a tunnel from the university machines to the SSH port of your PC. You leave that connection on when you are at university, which allows you to log back into your PC using the tunnel that was created by the SSH session.

This process has been described by http://www.vdomck.org/2005/11/reversing-ssh-connection.html; sorry for the link, but I don't want to copy all the information from there to here.

In principle, the command you issue from your PC is (assuming you want to connect from me@machine_b.cs.x.ca)

```
ssh -f -N -R 10000:localhost:22 me@machine_b.cs.x.ca
```

Then, when at university, you can connect to your home PC with the following command:

```
ssh -p 10000 nawshad@localhost
```

You can change the `10000` in both commands to a different value; just make sure that it is larger than 1024.

Note: while this tunnel is alive, everyone with access to `machine_b.cs.x.ca` can try to log into your system; make sure that you have good passwords.

To shut down the tunnel, just kill the corresponding ssh process, e.g. with

```
pkill -f 'ssh -f -N -R 10000:localhost:22 me@machine_b.cs.x.ca'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is very much a case for using SSH.

Unless your personal machine is registered with the DNS at your university (which is unlikely) you would be best off doing this via ipaddress.

First ensure that SSH is enabled on your personal machine. Check with `ps -ef | grep sshd | grep -v grep` and if not install and start sshd.

Once its running try to ssh to your machine via IP address, eg `ssh nawshad@0.0.0.0` you should be prompted for your password.

Good luck!

Comment: When I ran ps -ef | grep ssh, I found the following:nawshad   2898  2512  0 23:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sshd
Does it mean that I dont have ssh enabled in my personal laptop?

Comment: No. Thats the grep query itself. SSH is not running on your machine. Let me update the query to exclude that

Comment: This only works if the PC is actually directly connected to the internet, which is pretty unlikely.